# Is there a list of Savage Worlds character sheets for different settings?

Tags: savage-worlds, character-sheets

I'm trying to create a Savage Worlds setting based in the Assassin's Creed universe for a campaign I'm planning. I thought it would be fun to have myself and my players use a thematic Savage Worlds character sheet, of which there are hundreds, however I have no skill in design and don't fancy trying to make my own from scratch. So I was wondering if there's a consolidated list of the different templates.

Answer (score 1):

You could try browsing through Cheyenne Wright's [Savage Sheets](http://savagesheets.blogspot.com/)